# How to configure a Thinkpad TrackPoint Keybroad II on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: thinkpad, trackpoint

How can I change the TrackPoint sensitivity and speed settings of **Thinkpad TrackPoint Keybroad II** on Ubuntu 20.04? The
On Ubuntu 16.04, it is easy to set with `xinput set-prop "pointer:Lenovo TrackPoint Keyboard II" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 0.3`. However, on Ubuntu 20.04, the property `"Device Accel Constant Deceleration"` doesn't exist. I have set the `"libinput Accel Speed" 1`, but the trackpoint is still too slow and hard to use. For configuring the `etc/xorg.conf.d`, I can't login to the desktop. Could you please give me some suggestions to set the speed of trackpoint faster?

Here is the properties:

`$xinput list-props 18`

```
Device 'TrackPoint Keyboard II Mouse':
Device Enabled (168):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (170): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (303):   0
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (304):   0
libinput Scroll Methods Available (305):    0, 0, 1
libinput Scroll Method Enabled (306):   0, 0, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (307):   0, 0, 0
libinput Button Scrolling Button (308): 2
libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (309): 2
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (332):    0
libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (333):    0
libinput Accel Speed (310): 1.000000
libinput Accel Speed Default (311): 0.000000
libinput Accel Profiles Available (312):    1, 1
libinput Accel Profile Enabled (313):   1, 0
libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (314):   1, 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled (315): 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (316): 0
libinput Send Events Modes Available (288): 1, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (289):    0, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (290):    0, 0
Device Node (291):  "/dev/input/event18"
Device Product ID (292):    6127, 24801
libinput Drag Lock Buttons (317):   <no items>
libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (318):   1
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written a small python-tool which aims to mimic the windows-driver/tooling. It also allows you to set the pointer-speed/sensitivity. (Currently only tested with 2.4GHz usb-dongle): https://github.com/telecastr/tp2ctl

EDIT 09/09/2021:

**TL/DR:** The Trackpoint in the *Lenovo Trackpoint II* seems to emulate a *'Standard HID Mouse'*. To affect the sensitivity of the Trackpoint, you have to change the configuration of the 'emulator' within the keyboard. So after you plugged in the keyboard, run `tp2ctl -s 8` to tell the keyboard to set a higher sensitivity for the Trackpoint.

As far as I know (am I'm no expert on udev/libinput), as opposed to the internal `TPPS/2 IBM Trackpoint`-Trackpoint device, the `Lenovo Keyboard II Mouse` to `udev` is rather a *Plain Mouse* than a *Trackpoint*. For example a `grep -e "TrackPoint" /var/log/Xorg.0.log | awk '/is tagged by udev/'` returns on my machine:

```
(...)
[     3.335] (II) event8  - Lenovo TrackPoint Keyboard II Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
(...)
[     3.914] (II) event25 - TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint: is tagged by udev as: Mouse Pointingstick
```

This also seems to make sense from a another point of view: You can plug the *Lenovo Trackpoint Keyboard II* into *'anything'* that can handle standard USB HID mice and the *Trackpoint Keyboard II*-Trackpoint will 'just work'. What seems to happen is that the microcontroller in the *Trackpoint Keyboard II* is grabbing the output of the Trackpoint in the Keyboard and emulates a standard USB HID mouse. So to increase the `sensitivity` of the Trackpoint, we have to tell the micro in the Keyboard change its emulation-preferences in a way that a movement of the Trackpoint outputs *"more movement"* of the HID-Mouse (=*Increased Sensitivity* - Hopefully you get what I mean here ...).

To change these preferences 'in the keyboard', you have to send a particular stream of bytes (as listed on my repo) to tell the micro: "Hey, I want a lager HID-Mouse-Movement for a movement on the Trackpoint". This is **exactly how Lenovo allows you to set the sensitivity on MS Windows**. The tool I wrote sends the same stream of bytes as the Lenovo Windows-Tooling does (e.g. 'telling the Trackpoint to be more sensitive').

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: It would be wonderful if you figured out how to remove the past on middle click. It makes scrolling nearly unusable.