# Why is the Trackpoint Experiece on Windows better than Ubuntu?

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, trackpoint

I am an Ubuntu user since years but one thing that bothers me daily is the Trackpoint.
I have a Lenovo Carbon X1 (8. Gen) and when I dual boot into Windows the Trackpoint feels much more responsive and precise. I can't tell what it is exaclty.

Is there any way to get a similar experience on Ubuntu? Changing the accelaration with xinput helped a little bit.

Here is what I tried already:

```
# Get the id of the trackpint
xinput --list --short | grep -i trackpoint 

# See what props are available
xinput --list-props 21 

# Changed the accelaration to a value that feels more natural for me. 
xinput --set-prop 21 'libinput Accel Speed' -0.15
```

What are more things I can do? Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1362393/167115)?

Comment: @mchid I will check, thanks!

Comment: Another thing, I think we've mostly switched over to using `libinput` instead of `xinput` so that's something you might want to consider.

Comment: @mchid Thanks. I had a look and the script seems to be made for the external trackpoint keyboard. I will try to get it running for my "internal" laptop keyboard as well.